# I want to use axios with foreach in useEffect react Js but it gives me (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator) error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, axios, use-effect

I want to call axios in foreach but it gives me error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))"

```
let BooksInfo=["Atomic Habit","Feel the Fear . . . and Do It Anyway","The Four Agreements"]

export default BooksInfo;
```

this is my first try :

```
import './App.css';
import Card from "./Card"
import Books from "./Books"
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios"
import { promised } from 'q';
function App() {
  useEffect( ()=>{
    
    async function test(){
      

        await Promise.all(Books.forEach( (book)=>{
        console.log(book + "")
        const test1= axios.get(`https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=${book}`)
        console.log(test1)
      }))
    }
    test()
    console.log("outside")
  })
```

I also tried this way but it still gives me the same error

```
import './App.css';
import Card from "./Card"
import Books from "./Books"
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios"
import { promised } from 'q';
function App() {
  useEffect( ()=>{
    
    async function test(){
      

      const test1= await Promise.all(Books.forEach( (book)=>{
        console.log(book + "")
        axios.get(`https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=${book}`)
        .then(res=>{
          console.log("helooo")
          console.log(res)
          // console.log(tes)
        })
      }))
    }
    test()
    console.log("outside")
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a better approach, with this you can easily catch errors if there were any while making an API call.

```
  try {
    const result = await Promise.all(BooksInfo.map( (book)=>{
      console.log(book + "")
      const test1= axios.get(`https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=${book}`)
      return test1; // This is essential; this is how map func works
    }))

    console.info("API Result", result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Network error",error);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem could be on `Books`.
You iterate on them while you are exporting it as `BooksInfo` and importing it as `Books`, if the import isn't correct Books is `null` and therefore it triggers the error